# datatables server side processing(load on demand)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i am trying to do a server side processing which is load on demand , i am using mvc to develop my application

the following is my code on the datatables js class,

```
var initTrackingTable = function () {
    var table = $('#tableCategoryList');
    var daterange = $("#daterangepicker").val();

    val_CategoryName = $("#SearchTextBox").val();
    //val_Daterange = $("#trackingForm").find("[name='daterangepicker']").val();

    settingsInitEmpty = {
        ajax: ({
            url: "/Product/LoadCategoryData?category=" + val_CategoryName,
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json"
        }),
        // ### FOR SERVERSIDE LODING
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        filter: false,
        orderMulti: false,
        columns: [
                   { data: "category_id", name: "category_id", autoWidth: true },
                   { data: "category_name", name: "category_name", autoWidth: true, render: function (data, type, row) { return '<span class=""><a href="/Product/EditCategory?id=' + data + '" class="btnTrackingDetails" target="_blank">' + data + '</a></span>' } },
                   { data: "sort_order", name: "sort_order", autoWidth: true },
        ],
        initComplete: function (settings, json) {
            $("#tableCategoryList").parent().addClass("tableTransactionGridWrapper")
        }
    };
    categoryTable = table.DataTable(settingsInitEmpty);

}
```

on the category_name there, i wish to put the hyperlink, however the hyperlink i intend to put the category_id as a query string parameter so i am able to edit the category. may i ask is this achievable? if yes, how the code suppose to be?

Comment: in the current code now, the data variable show in the id is the category name

Comment: I deleted my answer...you got undefined why? what is you html structure? it should work (I will undelete later...accoding to the logic, it should works)